# How to find an element existence in document in javascript

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I simply created a html document. i start to test using `jest`. But getting invalid output. what is the correct way to test the element existence in document by `jest`?

here is my html:

```
<body>
<h2>Title</h2>
<input type="file" name="" class='title'>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

my js code :

```
window.onload = () => {

    const title = document.querySelector('h2');
    title.style = 'border:1px solid red';

    const input = document.querySelector('input');

    input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const file = event.srcElement.files;
        input.value = '';
    });

}
```

my test spec:

```
describe('first test', () => {

    it('should contain h2 element', () => {
        const h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
        expect(document.contains(h2)).toBe(true);
    });

});
```

but getting below error:

```
 expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      3 |     it('should contain h2 element', () => {
      4 |         const h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
    > 5 |         expect(document.contains(h2)).toBe(true);
        |                                       ^
      6 |     });
      7 |
      8 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (index.spec.js:5:39)
```

what is the correct approach to test my existing element in document?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like an issue with what `document.contains(h2)` is returning, not the equality test, The error indicates `Expected: true
    Received: false`

Comment: this is perhaps a dumb answer but why don't you just do `if((let el = document.querySelector('h2')))/*do your thing*/`? or `expect((h2 !== null)).toBe(true)`

Answer (score 1):

I would try as you've already tried to find the element with `querySelector`

```
...
expect((h2 !== null)).toBe(true);
...
```

Comment: `  expect(document.body.contains(h2)).toBe(true);` -> this is not works. but `expect((h2 !== null)).toBe(true);` -> this helps

Comment: `expect((h2 !== null)).toBe(true);` not works. only works on `false` params

Comment: @3gwebtrain what happens if you try `expect(!!h2).`

Comment: `expect((!!h2)).toBe(true);` - no luck. `Expected: true
    Received: false `

Comment: @3gwebtrain can you `console.log(h2)`? Can you see your element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208854/discussion-between-jsmith-and-3gwebtrain).